# How to add verified caller ID's using twilio Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio

Hey guys I am trying to use Twilio and add verified numbers to my list. So far it is just my own but I am trying to use the documentation with it saying this:

```
var accountSid = 'AC2394ac048859f6b48e7cdf630c29e631';
var authToken = "your_auth_token";
var Client = require('twilio').RestClient

var client = new Client(accountSid, authToken);


client.outgoingCallerIds.create({
    friendlyName: "My Home Phone Number",
    phoneNumber: "+14158675309"
}, function(err, callerId) {
if(err){
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(callerId.sid);
  }
});
```

to add them but all I get is this error saying this:

```
ReferenceError: client is not defined
client.outgoingCallerIds.list({ phoneNumber: "+14158675309" }, function(err, data) {
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure where you got the calling of `RestClient` on the Twilio module from, but if you could share that I will try to clear that up.

Instead of calling `RestClient` you can pass your account details straight to the module itself. To [list your outgoing caller IDs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids?code-sample=code-list-an-accounts-outgoing-caller-ids&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x) you can do the following:

```
const accountSid = 'your_account_';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.outgoingCallerIds.list({ phoneNumber: '+14158675309' }, function(callerId) {
  console.log(callerId.phoneNumber)
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

**edit**

### Creating a new outgoing caller ID

To verify a new outgoing caller ID via the API you need to do two things, make the API request to create a new outgoing caller ID and then display the resultant code that the user receiving the call will then have to enter into the phone to verify.

You do this like so:

```
const accountSid = 'your_account_sid';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.outgoingCallerIds
  .create({
    phoneNumber: '+14158675309',
  })
  .then(function(callerId) {
    // somehow display the validation code
    console.log(callerId.validationCode);
  });
```

Comment: How would you add it to your verified list. And the RestClient was on the documentation.

Comment: Which documentation page was it? I'll update my answer to show starting the verification process. :)

Comment: Ah, ok, that's using the 2.x series of the Twilio Node module. Check the top right corner of the code samples and make sure you have 3.x selected to get the latest documentation.